# A problem on Algebraic Geometric Codes

Tags: coding-theory

I am reading from https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~pmorandi/math601f01/LectureNotes.pdf. In page 50, if $k=0$ then why $\deg(G)<0$ and if $k=n$ why $\deg(G)>n-2$? Here $k$ is the dimension of the corresponding Goppa Code?

Comment: Too late an hour for me to check, but won't these follow from the fact that these Goppa Codes are defined using a curve of genus zero?

Comment: Yes, genus is zero.